# Unity doesn't autostart on second X screen

Tags: unity, compiz, multiple-monitors, autostart, twinview

I have two Nvidia cards both with 2 heads and both configured as TwinView, so I have Screen0 and Screen1 in my xorg.conf.

ccsm sees both screens (displays them in the Screens drop-down at the top left), but Unity starts only on Screen0 by default. The displays on Screen1 only show the default white screen and default X mouse cursor, when I hover over them.

Is this the normal, expected behavior?
Can I start Unity on Screen1 automatically without running custom shell scripts (like DISPLAY=:0.1 compiz --replace)?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know Unity will only show on the very first Monitor not the extended ones.
Unless they are TweenView and Cloned to Primary monitor. also if the Resolutions on the monitor are of different Size and ratio you may have to align the secondary monitors to overlay over the Unity portion of the main primary display.

Multiple monitor support is still kind of iffy on unity, and from what I read they will try to optimizes this on the next couple of releases of Ubuntu.